# Error with line 20: Required 'Int' found Double

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with line 20 and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong.  All I'm trying to do is display a a display of Celsius along with their respective Fahrenheit temperatures.  Celsius increments from 0-100 and Fahrenheit from 32 - 212.  This is otherwise far from finished and I'm aware it's still a mess.  I've gotten the data to to display but it's in one column as opposed to the two it's supposed to be in.

I appreciate your thoughts and input on this.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package celsiustofarenheittable;

/**
 *
 * @author these
 */
public class CelsiusToFarenheitTable {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double celsiusToFarenheit,farenheit,celsius = 0;
        celsiusToFarenheit = celsiusToFarenheit(farenheit,celsius);     // HERE!
        System.out.printf("Celsius \t Farenheit \n", celsius,farenheit);

        {
            for (celsius = 0; celsius <= 100; celsius += 10)
            {
                if (celsius <= 100 )
                    System.out.println(celsius);
            }

                while (farenheit <= 100){ 
                        System.out.println(farenheit * 1.8 + 32);
                        farenheit = farenheit + 10;
            }
            }     
      }    
    public static double celsiusToFarenheit(int celsius)
    {
        double farenheit;
        farenheit = math.round(celsius * 1.8 + 32);
        return farenheit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Naturally Line 20:

**celsiusToFarenheit = celsiusToFarenheit(farenheit,celsius);**

didn't bold like I wanted it to.

Comment: Please, change your title and your tags, there is no way to know what language you are talking about before looking at the post

Comment: Just put a big comment on line 20, to make it easier to find.  Formatting doesn't get applied to code blocks.  Also, can you change your title and post example expected vs actual outputs, just to make sure we're crystal clear on what you're going for.

Comment: How many arguments does the method celsiusToFarenheit expect? How many arguments do you pass to the method? What is the expected type of the argument(s) of the method? What is the type of the argument(s) you pass? https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1H_OTif2H8KJjy1zkq6xr7pXax/13-Trou-Forme-Assortis-Color-Enfants-Jeu-ducatif-Jouet-enfants-En-Bois-de-Construction-Jouets-T30.jpg

Comment: Your celsiusToFarenheit method wants a parameter (celsius) that is an integer. In your main you declare celsius as double and also call your method with TWO parameters (both double). You only need the celsius as a parameter, so if you want to give it as an integer, declare it as such or convert it from double. If you want to use decimal celsius, better declare it as non-integer.

Comment: As a style point, I wouldn't name a function and a variable the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You are really close, the actual conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit is correct.

So your issue is that you are passing two `doubles`, `farenheit` and `celsius` to your method `celsiusToFarenheit(int celsius)` As you can see from the method declaration, it requires just `int celsius`. From this celsius value you are doing the conversion to Fahrenheit.

So for instance:

```
int celsius = 10;
double fahrenheit = celsiusToFarenheit(celsius);
```

This produces a fahrenheit of 50, which is as to be expected

Answer (score 0):

The `celsiusToFarenheit` method is expecting one `integer` parameter and you are providing two `double` arguments in the line 20.

My suggestion is to make your celsius variable match the method argument type (`int`), and provide just the celsius variable in the line 20:

```
celsiusToFarenheit(celsius)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so many unnecessary variables and other stuffs that you don't really need. I have modified your code, made it as simple as possible, enjoy:

```
    public class CelsiusToFarenheitTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    double fahrenheit = 32.0, celsius = 0.0;
    System.out.printf("Celsius \t Farenheit \n", celsius,fahrenheit);


        for (celsius = 10; celsius <=100; celsius+=10)
        {
            System.out.print(celsius);
            System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.println(celsius * 1.8 + 32);
            fahrenheit = fahrenheit + 10;
        }
  }
```

}

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see what I was going wrong.  I made the mistake of using two loops for whatever reason.  I had to make some changes in order to get the method to work.  If I want to increase or decrease decimals being displayed, since it's being displayed using printf, could I not use %2d  within the respective quotes to increase and %0d to decrease an INT?

Comment: @SophiaGreen, not sure what you by increase or decrease of displayed decimals? Do you mean you want to expand your table further by adding new values (ex. celcius = 150, fahrenheit = ???). In that case all is handled within `for()`statement. `Printf`has nothing to do in this specific case, because it is called only one at the top of your program. The celsius and fahrenheit values are not INT, they are Double, that's why you see the results as ex. 100.00. If you want to see 100, then use just int instead of double

Comment: My fault, being at this for a little bit fried my brain.  I'm trying to determine why the typical commands I would use to adjust the amount of decimal places isn't working.  If I wanted 2 decimal places, would I not insert %2d within the double quotes in the printf statement?

Comment: @SophiaGreen, here is a link about how printf works. https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

Comment: I really appreciate the link and help you're providing me.  I understand that when using the printf now, that in order to left or right align the data being displayed, I should type System.out.printf("%3d ", celsius); however, I must be missing something since its not right aligning when I insert that code.

Comment: @SophiaGreen, can you provide your code so I see what you are trying to do? Do you not want to use the code I gave above or you really need to use printf?